# Parse and Extract unique value from a text file efficiently

Tags: java, performance, file, data-structures

I have two tsv files to parse and extract values from each file. Each line may have 4-5 attributes per line. The content of both the files are as below :

```
1   44539   C   T   19.44  
1   44994   A   G   4.62  
1   45112        TATGG  0.92  
2   43635   Z   Q    0.87  
3   5672    AAS      0.67
```

There are some records in each file that have first 3 or 4 attributes same but different value. I want to retain higher value of such records and prepare new file with all unique values. For example:

```
1   44539   C   T   19.44

1   44539   C   T   25.44
```

I need to retain one with the higher value in above case record with value 25.44

I have drafted code for this however after few minutes the program runs slow. I am reading each record from a file forming a key value pair with the first 3 or 4 records as key  and last record as value and storing it in hashmap and use it to again write to a file. Is there a better solution?
also how can I test if my code is giving me correct output in file?

One file is of size 498 MB with 23822225 records and other is of 515 MB with 24500367 records.

I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error for the file with size 515 MB.

Is there a better way I can code to execute the program efficiently with out increasing heap size.

I might have to deal with larger files in future, what would be the trick to solve such problems?

```
public class UniqueExtractor {
    private int counter = 0; 

    public static void main(String... aArgs) throws IOException {
        UniqueExtractor parser = new UniqueExtractor("/Users/xxx/Documents/xyz.txt");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        parser.processLineByLine();

        parser.writeToFile();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long total_time = endTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("done in " + total_time/1000 + "seconds ");
    }


    public void writeToFile()
    {
        System.out.println("writing to a file");

        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/Users/xxx/Documents/xyz_unique.txt", "UTF-8");
            Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                sb.setLength(0);
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                sb.append(pair.getKey());
                sb.append(pair.getValue());
                writer.println(sb.toString());
                writer.flush();
                it.remove();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public UniqueExtractor(String fileName) 
    {
        fFilePath = fileName;
    }

    private HashMap<String, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();

    public final void processLineByLine() throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(new File(fFilePath))) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                //System.out.println("ha");
                System.out.println(++counter);
                processLine(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }

    protected void processLine(String aLine)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] split = aLine.split("  ");
        BigDecimal bd = null;
        BigDecimal bd1= null;

        for (int i=0; i < split.length-1; i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(i);
            //System.out.println();

            sb.append(split[i]);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        bd= new BigDecimal((split[split.length-1]));
        //System.out.print("key is" + sb.toString());
        //System.out.println("value is "+ bd);

        if (map.containsKey(sb.toString()))
        {
            bd1 = map.get(sb.toString());
            int res = bd1.compareTo(bd);
            if (res == -1)
            {
                System.out.println("replacing ...."+ sb.toString() + bd1 + " with " + bd);
                map.put(sb.toString(), bd);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(sb.toString(), bd);
        }
        sb.setLength(0);
    }

    private String fFilePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple main things you may want to consider to improve the performance of this program.

## Avoid `BigDecimal`

While `BigDecimal` is very useful, it has a lot of overhead, both in speed and space requirements. According to your examples, you don't have very much precision to worry about, so I would recommend switching to plain floats or doubles. These would take a mere fraction of the space (so you could process larger files) and would probably be faster to work with.

## Avoid `StringBuilder`

This is not a general rule, but applies in this case: you appear to be parsing and then rebuilding `aLine` in `processLine`. This is very expensive, and probably unnecessary. You could, instead, use `aLine.lastIndexOf('\t')` and `aLine.substring` to cut up the String with much less overhead.

These two should significantly improve the performance of your code, but don't address the overall algorithm.

## Dataset splitting

You're trying to handle enough data that you might want to consider not keeping all of it in memory at once.

For example, you could split up your data set into multiple files based on the first field, run your program on each of the files, and then rejoin the files into one. You can do this with more than one field if you need more splitting. This requires less memory usage because the splitting program does not have to keep more than a single line in memory at once, and the latter programs only need to keep a chunk of the original data in memory at once, not the entire thing.

You may want to try the specific optimizations outlined above, and then see if you need more efficiency, in which case try to do dataset splitting.

Comment: Thanks col6y. I tried with first two options and performance did improved significantly. However I think if larger file is presented to me then I would have to go by the third suggestion in you provided.

Comment: is there a way by which i can test if the output i am getting is the desired output?

Comment: Try small datasets and see if they work? If you want a more in-depth answer than that, ask a separate question.